# My MacOSX terminal doesn't show the current directory

Tags: shell-script, command-line, osx, zsh, bashrc

No matter what directory I enter, the terminal always shows me the root directory which is "Nidas-MBP"

```
Nidas-MBP% cd Projects
Nidas-MBP% ls
09-Selector-Exercise-Starter.zip    My Little Form
09_Selector_Exercise_Starter        Prefix Free File
Blog                                Recursion Practice
Callbacks                           Themes
Callbacks-Exercise                  Todo-Vanilla
Copywriting                         css3-contact-form.zip
Freelancer Theme                    webpack-deepdive
Frog Chase

Nidas-MBP% cd webpack-deepdive
Nidas-MBP% ls
es6-todomvc
Nidas-MBP%
```

I have tried adding the following command to end of the ~/.bashrc file and the ~/.profile file but the terminal still remained unchanged.

```
PS1='[\u \W$] '
```

When I run `echo "$PS1"` it says

```
%m%#
```

I found two lines `PS1=[ \W]\$` `PS1='[ \W]$ '` inside `~/.bash_profile`, so I replaced them both with `PS1='[\u \W$] '` and typed `source ~/.bash_profile`. In response, my terminal started saying `[\u \W$]` instead of `Nidas-MBP`.

I have no idea what I should do now to bring it back to the way it used to be.

Comment: I cannot reproduce `Darwin Kernel Version 17.4.0`.  Have you sourced the `.bashrc` and `.profile` files after making the changes?  and/or restarted your terminal?

Comment: @Jesse_b I am not sure what you mean by "sourced the files" but yes I did quit and restart my terminal after the change in the files.

Comment: What is the current value of `$PS1`?

Comment: @RalfFriedl How do I check that?

Comment: With `echo "$PS1"`

Comment: @RalfFriedl Got it. It says   %m%#

Comment: That's not the root directory.  The root directory is named `/`.  (It's not a directory at all, in fact.  And you are not using the Bourne Again shell.)

Comment: @JdeBP I had no idea that command was specific to the Bourne Again shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no idea there was a difference in commands between bash and zsh. Apparently, I was supposed to type `PS1='%m %1d$ '` instead. So I did that inside the `~/.zshrc` file and it works now.

https://superuser.com/questions/1108413/zsh-prompt-with-current-working-directory

Answer (score 1):

Completely reworked per JdeBP's observation, this is `zsh` not `bash`.

`bash` and `zsh` are two different shells, and use two different sets of files when you start them. `bash` uses `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, and `.profile`. `zsh` uses `.zprofile`, `.zshrc`, and others.

`zsh` also uses different syntax for dictating the prompt. `echo $PROMPT` will tell you the prompt's current setting. To display, e.g., your current directory at the prompt, add this to `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc` (if `ZDOTDIR` is not set, `zsh` will use `HOME` instead):

`PROMPT='%~> '`
[Source](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_14.html)

Then either `source ~/.zshrc` or restart the terminal.

Comment: You were right. I found two lines 
`PS1=[ \W]\$ 
PS1='[ \W]$ '`

inside ~/.bash_profile, so I replaced them both with `PS1='[\u \W$] ' ` and typed `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Now my terminal says `[\u \W$]` instead of `Nidas-MBP`

Comment: Psst! M. Kruse!  There is a subtle clue, buried in a question comment made by the questioner, that the questioner has mis-labelled the question and is in fact using the Z shell.

Comment: @JdeBP I see it now, according to Google the default prompt for zsh is `%m%#`. Being unfamiliar with `zsh`, I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there must be something that changes `PS1` after you set it.

To find where you can

- Use `grep` in your home directory and in `/etc`.

  ```
  grep PS1 -r /etc $HOME
  ```
- Use `set -x` after you set `PS1` to see where it is changed.
- Use `strace` to find out which file contains that value.

Comment: After I change the ~/.profile file and add the line PS1='[\u \W$] ' to the end of the file. Typing echo "PS1" to the terminal returns PS1.

Comment: You should not echo `"PS1"`, but `"$PS1"`. And just changing the file will have no effect, you need to login again. An alternative is `source .profile`, but then you don't know whether it will work on login.

Comment: Okay I've tried logging out and back in after changing the ~/.profile file but I still have the same problem. The root stills says Nidas-MBP no matter what. Typing grep in the command line showed me 

`usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]`

Also using echo "$PS1" returned %m%# after logging back in.

Comment: I added the command for grep.